# How to Show snackbar when no internet connection?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I'm tried to build my mobile apps for the first time. How to display Snackbar if there is no internet connection?

This is for a flutter apss, with connectivity: ^0.4.3+1 packages

Here's my connectionStatus

```
class NetworkSensitive extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;


  NetworkSensitive({
    this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var connectionStatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context);

    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityStatus.WiFi) {
      return child;
    }

    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Cellular) {
      return Container(child: Text('Koneksi Mobile'), );
    }

    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Offline) {
      return Container(child: Text('Koneksi Offline'), );
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my home to display snackbar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const int CounterMargins = 60;

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        body: Column(children: [
         NetworkSensitive(child: _buildSimpleSnackBar(),

  }

   _buildSimpleSnackBar() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text("your'e Offline"),
          );
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text(
          "Show Simple SnackBar",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That code is works to check the connection and display snackbar after press the button, but how to display it without press the button

Comment: You should check for async function, steams and BLoC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [listener](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) for connectivity state change, as seen in the package page.

For toast message, I am using a the [FlutterToast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast#-readme-tab-) package:

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();

}
class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

  var subscription;
  var connectionStatus;

  @override
  void initState() {
    subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {         
      setState(() => connectionStatus = result );
    });
    checkInternetConnectivity();
    checkLoginStatus();
    super.initState();
  }

  checkInternetConnectivity() {
    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      return Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Check your internet connection",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container();

  }
}
```

The connectivity package also provides the mobile and wifi network change. Just use `ConnectivityResult.mobile` and `ConnectivityResult.wifi`

Comment: It only worked for me when I put `checkInternetConnectivity();` inside the `Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen()` block (moving it one line up.). Combined it with `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar()` and `AppSettings.openWIFISettings();`

Answer (score 0):

Their is a listener for connectivity state change, as seen in the package page https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity .

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {

  var connectionStatus;

  @override
    initState() {
    super.initState();

    subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      // Got a new connectivity status!
      setState(() => connectionStatus = result);
    })
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityStatus.WiFi) {
      return child;
    }

    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Cellular) {
      return Container(child: Text('Koneksi Mobile'), );
    }

    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Offline) {
      return Container(child: Text('Koneksi Offline'), );
    }
  }

  // Be sure to cancel subscription after you are done
  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription.cancel();
  }
```